# Create a Bulk user creation script on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, user-management, users

The script below (create_user_list.bat) loops and creates 30 users.  It works well on Windows Server2003 but is breaking on Server 2008.  The error that is received is 'System error 5 has occured. Access is denied'.

Is there a permision level that needs to be changed in order to run the script?

```
set number=0

:start_loop
set /A number=%number%+1
if %number% GTR 30 goto end

net user company%number% i3z9nto! /add /comment:"10.5.2011" /expires:never /fullname:"Company User %number%" /passwordchg:no
net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" company%number% /add

goto start_loop

:end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run it with UAC elevation.

If you're running the batch file directly, right-click and `Run As Administrator`.  If you're doing it from a command prompt, then run `cmd.exe` as administrator instead.